# How to verify signed cookies are valid on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I'm working on a React application.  I am defining user roles and restricting access to components based on the permissions level of the role. I am looking in to using signed cookies to set the permissions from a php backend.  When I determine whether the application should render a component based on the data in the cookie, how do I verify that the roles in the cookie have not been redefined by the user without sending the cookie to the backend?

Comment: I don't think not rendering the component is the right idea - I think the component should be free to load, but the content within that component, which would be fetched from the server, wouldn't load because the server couldn't verify your cookie.

Comment: @TylerSebastian: I suggest you put your comment in an answer as this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the right approach, in my opinion. The components should be free to load - if there's something built-in to a component that an un-authenticated user shouldn't be able to see, there's nothing stopping someone from going into the source and discovering it themselves.

You have to take a different approach for front-end applications - all the components and UI are public. When the component fetches information from the server to display to the user, the server will still do the session authentication and respond with a 4xx (401 would be a good place to start) and the component would handle that response appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If modifying the role in the cookie would allow the user to gain more rights, then the solution is not to check the validity of the cookie on the client side. The user could also modify the client side script to circumvent/skip the integrity check of the cookies, and you would have the same problem as before.

The only correct solution is, that the user won't get those informations/scripts at the first place. So you need to check on the server side what informations are allowed to be send to the client, only send the data the user is allowed to see, and verify all actions the user sends to the server on the server side before you execute them.