# Token based authentication for react front end

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, jwt, restful-authentication

I am trying to use JWT based authentication, I am not sure how to protect routes, if i save token in cookie like below

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

const cookies = new Cookies();

const authService = {
  isAuthenticated () {
    if (cookies.get('auth')) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },
  signIn (data, cb) {
    cookies.set('auth', true, { path: '/' });
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  },
  signOut (cb) {
    cookies.remove('auth');
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
  }
};

export default authService;
```

it will check auth cookie and allow user to routes. How can i make routes protected and verify each time token is valid or not rather than just checking token is present or not.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => (
      authService.isAuthenticated()
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={
          {
            pathname: '/',
            state: { target: props.location }
          }}
        />
    )}
  />
);
```

it's possible to bypass this check by manually adding an object to cookie using browser dev tools, how can i protect my frontend routes.

Comment: I've answered a question similar to this previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840726/how-to-verify-signed-cookies-are-valid-on-the-front-end/42841167#42841167 - the TL;DR is that, in a SPA/frontend application the data is what is private, not the routes.

Comment: I want to protect both route views and data. is there any approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's look like you aren't using JWT correctly,
when you sign your jwt in your server side, the client receive an encrypted token that could be partially decoded in your client side, but each login \ refresh \ etc the token should be validated in your server side, where you can fully decode the token, if the token isn't real token \ expired the server should response an error, and any request with this token shouldn't proceed.

i would strongly suggest that you would read more about jwt, you might look at:

[jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/) - official site

[jwt-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-express) - an npm package for server side validating token

Comment: Tom Mendelson, I am doing jwt.verify in serverside, the token in cookie is generated by server and. Server side routing is protected by JWT middleware, I want front end route protection.

Comment: What is the client side protection should achieve? 
if you try to protect the data only, the server side validation is enough, because when the user enter to the page and try to load the data the server would reject the request because of the fake token.
if you want to protect the route himself (i don't sure why) then you can use the webpack split chunks option (https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/), where you can require an pages \ routes dynamically after server validation \ etc